# Does regular expression have any limit?

Tags: regex

I found I can't replace some characters in a substring:

like this, I want to remove the 'a' in the double quoted substring

```
origin = 'a hello "a world a" any other text'
```

Is there a regular expression can solve this, or there are some limit when use regular expression?

Comment: As in, you want to replace all `a` that are enclosed in double quotes?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace the `a` in the double quoted substring, but not other  `a` characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short way consists to replace all quoted parts and to use an other replacement for the eventual isolated "a" in these parts:

```
re.sub(r'"[^"]*"', lambda x: re.sub(r'\ba\b', 'X', x.group(0)), s)
```

IMO, it's the more simple way.

---

If you want to do it with only one replacement, you need to use the regex module and a more complicated pattern based on the anchor `\G` to ensure the contiguity of matches between quotes:

```
import regex

p = regex.compile(r'''
(?:
    \G(?!\A)
  |
    (?:\A|") # from the start of the string or from the closing quote
    [^"]*+   # all characters that are not a quote

    # skip quoted parts without an isolated "a" and reach the next opening quote
    (?: " [^"a]*(?:(?:\Ba|a\B)[^"a]*)* " [^"]*)*+ 

    "        # the opening quote
) 
[^"a]*+(?:(?:\Ba|a\B)[^"a]*)*+ # all characters before an "a"
\Ka''', regex.VERBOSE)

result = p.sub('X', s)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/iI4oD0/1)

This pattern can be shorten with the help of backtracking control verbs to skip quoted parts or end of quoted part without an isolated "a":

```
regex.compile(r'''
    (?: \G(?!\A) | " )

    [^"a]*(?:(?:\Ba|a\B)[^"a]*)*

    (?: "[^"]*(*SKIP)(*F))?
    \K a
''', regex.VERBOSE)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/iI4oD0/2)

Comment: Great!, use `re.sub` in `re.sub` is a beautiful way to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what language you are using, but for Perl you would:

```
$origin =~ s|a hello "a world a" any other text|A|g;
```

The key is the g at the end is for global, which will handle all substitutions in the string.  Without g it stops after the first one.